# ERROR In SQL Developer create domain Error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE DOMAIN Product_Stock number
    DEFAULT 0
    CONSTRAINT VALID-product_Stock CHECK(between 0 and 100);
```

```
오류 보고 -
SQL 오류: ORA-00901: CREATE 명령어가 부적합합니다
00901. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE command"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I want to create a domain. However, an error occurs.
How solving?

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `create domain`?

Comment: Perhaps you mean a namespace, like Products.ProductItem?  If this is the case, just create the stored proc, or table using the fully qualified name.   e.g.  CREATE TABLE Products.ProductItem(........

Answer (score 0):

You get an error message `invalid CREATE command`, because there are no domains in the Oracle database. Trying to create a domain with `CREATE DOMAIN ...` is therefore invalid.